# Segmentation Fault in push_back()

Tags: c++, stl

I am getting segmentation fault in push_back(), I have given below a sample code of my  project. I am not using image(IplImage*) inside the vec since i am clearing the temp (IplImage*) after push_back()

My doubt is this, should I replace...

```
a.cands.push_back(b);
```

...with...

```
 b.frontImg = NULL;
 a.cands.push_back(b);
```

...?

The program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<highgui.h>
#include<cv.h>

using namespace std;

struct B
{
  IplImage* frontImg;
  vector<int> num;
  B()
  {
    frontImg = NULL;
  }
}; 

struct A
{
  vector<B> cands;
  IplImage* img1;
  A()
  {
    img1 = NULL;
  }
};

vector<A> vec;

int main()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
  {
    struct B b;
    IplImage* temp = cvLoadImage("logo.jpg");
    b.frontImg = temp;

    struct A a;

    for (int j = 0; j<1000; j++)
    {
      a.cands.push_back(b);
    }

    vec.push_back(a); //here

    cvReleaseImage(&temp);

    //some porcess
  }
}
```

Error message from comments

```
 #0 0x000000353a0328a5 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6  
 #1 0x000000353a034085 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6  
 #2 0x000000353a0707b7 in __libc_message () from /lib64/libc.so.6  
 #3 0x000000353a0760e6 in malloc_printerr () from /lib64/libc.so.6  
 #4 0x000000353a079b64 in _int_malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6  
 #5 0x000000353a07a911 in malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6  
 #6 0x0000000000688a7d in operator new(unsigned long)  
 #7 ???  
 #8 0x0000000000563fdd in std::_Vector_base<CvPoint, std::allocator<CvPoint> >::_M_allocate (this=0x7f31ad14bb90, __n= 1096) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_ve‌​ctor.h:140  
 #9 0x0000000000560491 in std::_Vector_base<CvPoint, std::allocator<CvPoint> >::_Vector_base (this=0x7f31ad14bb90, __n= 1096, __a=...) at /usr/lib/gcux/4.4.7./include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_vector.h:113  
 #10 0055ebc1 in std::vector<CvPoint, std::allocator<CvPoint> >::vector (this=0x7f31ad14bb90, __x= std::vector of length 1096, capacity 1096 = {../include/c++/  
 #11 ???  
 #12 ???  
 #13 ???  
 #14 0x000000000055f346 in std::vector<LPCandidate, std::allocator<LPCandidate> >::push_back (this=0x7f31ac00ddb0, __x= ...) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_ve‌​ctor.h:737  
 #15 0x0000000000556689 in KLPR::TrManager::segregateLane (this=0x7f31ac0008e8, candLPV= std::vector of length 6, capacity 32 = {...}, candIndex=0x7f31b3ffd500) at MyProject/src/TrManager.cpp:2026
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong in the code you've posted - runs fine on [ideone here](http://ideone.com/TRL3Rh) with mock cvXXX functions and types - either `cvReleaseImage()` isn't releasing all your memory or your "some porcess" [sic] has undefined behaviour (e.g. corrupting the heap) and that coincidentally bites during `push_back()`.  I can't see why you'd load an image then release it without doing anything with it, so I think you're not giving us a realistic view of your problem.

Comment: above given code is not crashing, but this is what i have done in my project.. It is difficult give actual code.. So I have created a similar code as that of my project

Comment: @deepak: That's not a segmentation fault, it's the heap manager aborting because you've corrupted the heap (by writing to an invalid pointer, or out of bounds of an allocated block of memory). I'd use Valgrind to find the invalid write.

Comment: @Mike Seymour  please can u explain  ?

Comment: How can I prevent that ? Is this because of my size of the vector is very high ???????

Comment: @deepak: Some code (possibly not what you've posted) either writes through a pointer to a deleted object (or some other invalid pointer), or beyond the end of an allocated block of memory, or something along those lines. This corrupts the data structures used by `malloc` to manage the heap used for dynamically allocated memory. A later call to `malloc` (which happens indirectly when the vector increases its capacity during `push_back`) notices this corruption and aborts the program, since it's in a state where it can't allocate memory. A tool like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) can help.

Comment: MyStruct& currCand = candLPV[i];
MyStruct& lastCand = myVec[laneNumber].candLP.back();
if (1)
{           
  lastCand = currCand;
}

Comment: @ Mike Seymour will above code create problem ?

Comment: @deepak In your real code, the structures `A` and `B` - do they delete their `IplImage*` members in destructor, or assignment operator, or copy constructor?

Comment: No.. I haven't written any destructor inside the structure..

Comment: Do you use cvLoadImage or cvCaptureImage in your real code?

Comment: I am using cvLoadImage,

Comment: @ Mike Seymour : can you give a small program which gives segmentation fault in push_back() due to memory corruption ?

Comment: @deepak: I could, but it wouldn't be helpful. As I said, this isn't a segmentation fault, it's heap corruption. If you can't find where you're writing to a dodgy address just by reading the program, use a tool like Valgrind to find it for you.

Comment: @ Mike Seymour: I have asked code for learning purpose..

Answer (score 2):

The code posted looks dangerous with

- raw pointers
- no destructor / copy constructor / assignment operator (Rule of 3 (C++03), Rule of 5 (C++11)
- no clear ownership of the data.
- potential use of data after delete.
- missing check if clLoadImage fails.

see comments:

```
struct B b;
IplImage* temp = cvLoadImage("logo.jpg");
b.frontImg = temp;

struct A a;

for (int j = 0; j<1000; j++)
  a.cands.push_back(b);
```

Now you have 1000 elements pointing to the image returned by cvLoadImage, I will assume you load different images for each `b.frontImg` in your real program.

```
vec.push_back(a); //here
```

A's default copy constructor is called and if `a` is not used anymore `a`s default destructor is call, which deletes all `B`s in its vector. None of which is faulty in the shown program part.

```
cvReleaseImage(&temp);
```

Now you release what those 1000 elements are pointing too (if cvLoadImage, again not a problem if `b.frontImg` is not used later.

```
//some process
```

Here you hopefully don't use the just released image through the pointer in B.

---

Now to your question, yes you should use

```
b.frontImg = NULL;
a.cands.push_back(b);
```

As it removes a lot of problems as no one now can copy or delete the image through `b` (if you remember to delete the image after).

---

An example of how the raw pointers are dangerous, add

```
~B() { delete frontImg; } // or some user of B decides to delete frontImg itself.
```

to the code, but no copy constructor or copy assignment operator. Now every time you do a

```
a.cands.push_back(b);  // implicit copy construct of a new b.
```

`b` is later destroyed when it runs out of scope. You effectively push back a `b` which will point to a deleted image, and when you delete `a` you delete the image again through the vector's `b`, thus corrupting the heap.